# What is max_obstacle_height param in costmap_common of navigation stack?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wiki gives this definition:The maximum height in meters of a sensor reading considered valid. This is usually set to be slightly higher than the height of the robot. Setting this parameter to a value greater than the global max_obstacle_height parameter has no effect. Setting this parameter to a value less than the global max_obstacle_height will filter out points from this sensor above that height.

I understand that any data read by this sensor above this height will be filtered out , why this parameter needed in a planar scanner ?

am i understanding this in wrong way ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358412/what-is-max_obstacle_height-param-in-costmap_common-of-navigation-stack-?/) by [Shiva_uchiha](https://answers.ros.org/users/37455/shiva_uchiha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2020-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer: In a planar scanner, it is not needed.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2020-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1